# JQuery and Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a test chrome extension to see how JQuery works with chrome extensions.  From the code provided I think it should change the background of the popup to yellow.

I have tried loading the jquery.js using a content script and using background.  When I load it via the background scripts command, it shows that jquery.js was loaded.

Here are my files:

manifest.json

```
    {
  "name": "Hello World!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "My first Chrome extension.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

popup.html

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <script src='jquery.js'></script>
    <script src='content.js'></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

content.js

```
$('a').css({'background-color': 'yellow'});
```

I have the jquery.js in my extension folder as well.  If someone get either give me something else to try to get this working, or could show me a really good working example of a chrome extension that links jquery, that would be great!

Comment: Exactly, what's the problem? It should work. Take a look at this site: http://carl-topham.com/theblog/post/creating-chrome-extension-uses-jquery-manipulate-dom-page/

Comment: When I load the plugin and click it, it just shows a small popup box with a little gray box in the lower right and corner.

Comment: I tried that link, but I still cannot get it to work.  I updated the manifest_version 2 , got jQuery 1.10.2 min in the folder and when I click the plugin nothing happened.  I also updated the background_page to "background": {"page": "background.html"}

Comment: You have mixed things up a little. What are you trying t achieve ? Make the background of each `a` element on 'http://www.google.com/*' automatically yellow ? Or have a button, that when clicked turns the background of each `a` element of the active tab's page yellow ?

Comment: @user2200175 Knock, knock ! Did you try my proposed solution below ? Did you get this to work ?

Answer (score 11):

You've been short of mixing things up that shouldn't go together.

One thing you've been doing wrong:
Since you don't want a popup to appear when clicking on your browser-action button, you should not specify a "default-popup":

```
...
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"   // <-- this line should go away
},
...
```

With that said, the best way (imo) to approach the problem is the following:

1. Have your background-page (or better yet **[event-page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)**) listen for the **[chrome.browserAction.onClicked](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked)** event.
   (Note that in order for the event to be triggered, no default-popup must be set up.)
2. When that happens, use **[programmatic injection](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi)** to inject `jquery.min.js` and `content.js` into the active tab's page, using **[chrome.tabs.executeScript](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript)**.
3. In order for the aforementioned steps to be possible, you must also declare the necessary **[permissions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html)**, namely `"tabs"` and the URL **[match-patterns](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html)** of the pages that should be accessible to your extension (e.g. `"http://*/*"` and `"https://*/*"` to have access to all pages with the **http** and **https** schemes).

I would also suggest, taking a good look at the **[manifest specification](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html)** in order to familiarize with the available fields and possible values.

---

Finally, some demo source code to get you started (I know all that info at once can be overwhelming):

**Extension folder structure:**

```
       _______________LinkHighlighter_______________
      |                      |                      |
manifest.json               img                     js
                             |                      |__background.js
                        icon<XX>.png(*)             |__content.js
                                                    |__jquery.min.js
(*): <XX> = 16, 19, 38, 48, 128
```

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Link Highlighter",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "...",
    "icons": {
         "16": "img/icon16.png",
         "48": "img/icon48.png",
        "128": "img/icon128.png"
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Link Highlighter",
        "default_icon": {
            "19": "img/icon19.png",
            "38": "img/icon38.png"
        }
    },
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

**background.js:**

```
// When the user clicks the browser-action button...
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    // ...inject 'jquery.min.js' and...
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        file: "js/jquery.min.js",
        allFrames: true,
        runAt: "document_idle"
    });
    // ...inject 'content.js' into the active tab's page
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        file: "js/content.js",
        allFrames: true,
        runAt: "document_idle"
    });
});
```

**content.js:**

```
$("a").css({ "background-color": "yellow" });
```

---

Don't hesitate to come back, should you have further questions/problems :)

---

***For the sake of completeness...***
...let me just mention that thre are other approaches possible, sush as:

1. Using page-actions instead of a browser-action.
2. Injecting every page with your content scripts, and trigger the highlighting by means of message-passing from the background-page to the content scripts.