# Google Chrome Extension: jQuery doesn't work in background.js

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For some reason, **jQuery** doesn't work in my **background.js** in my Google Chrome extension.

Suppose my plugin tells me all the images on the page. I verified that it gets to the below method OK, but it stops at the jQuery loop.

First, manifest.json: note I'm including jQuery, the file exists:

```
{
    "name": "Gallery",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Gallery", 
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "G.png" 
    },  
    "background": {
        "persistent": true,
        "scripts": ["jquery-1.11.2.min.js", "background.js"]  
    },     
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "contextMenus", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
    ], 
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://*/*",
                "https://*/*"
            ],
            "css": ["contentstyle.css"],
        "js": ["jquery-1.11.2.min.js", "contentscript.js"]
        }
    ], 
    "icons": {
              "32": "G.png" 
  }
}
```

**background.js** uses the jQuery syntax:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(scanImages);

function scanImages()
{
    // IT GETS HERE - THIS IS OK
    alert('Clicked plugin button, about to start looping thru IMG...'); 

    // BUT STOPS HERE: JQUERY DOESN'T EXECUTE
    $("img").each(function() {
        alert($(this).prop("src"));
    });

    // ANOTHER JQUERY THAT DOESN'T WORK
    alert('Page title = ' + $(document).find("title").text());
}
```

Comment: so I can't use jQuery in background.js? Only in the popup?

Comment: An example with code: [JQuery and Chrome Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19477655) For more examples simply google `stackoverflow chrome extension access web page from popup or background page`

Comment: Another example: [Chrome's tabs.executeScript - passing parameters and using libraries?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4979785)

Comment: ok I got it. needs to go in a content script. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the DOM of any page you need to use content scripts as explained in the comments. Though there is another way of accessing more than one scripts in your background.js.

Add the `jquery-1.11.2.min.js` in your background.html file.

```
....
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
....
```

`manifest.json -->`

```
"background": {
    "page": "path/to/background.html",
    "persistent": true
}
```

You don't have to define the scripts key also, just define your background.html page and the scripts you want in the head section of the html file. I Hope it helps.

Comment: this answer is incorrect. yes it will make jquery work on background, but the actual issue is that the op needs to understand extension arquitecture. the code will never work even with the library included.

Comment: Oh Yes, my bad, he is trying to access DOM from the background.js script which don't have access to web page. Yes the code will go in a content script.

Comment: @ZigMandel Updated my answer, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Downvoting for using an old mechanism when `scripts` key is just fine, and only answering the actual answer in a vague comment.